# MySQL finding products viewed by others

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains products viewed by clients, it looks like this:

```
| id | visitor_id |  product  |

| 1  |   51a474f  |     5     |
| 2  |   51a474f  |     3     |
| 3  |   51a474f  |     3     |
| 4  |   207ed9e  |     3     |
| 4  |   207ed9e  |     5     |
| 5  |   47d98ee  |     4     |
| 6  |   47d98ee  |     3     |
| 7  |   47d98ee  |     2     |
```

And if someone visits e.g. product no. 5, I'd like to get all visitors who also visit the same product and then group all products (which id is other than 5) and count them by number of visits.

I know I could do this with multiple queries, but I think single query would be better than that solution.

Comment: do you have visitor ID and product ID on that page?

Comment: Here is a fiddle for your question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e34ff/1/0, the query is not a complete solution though ;)

Comment: ID is only row number and it's not relevant in this case :). Here's a list of what I'd do:

Example: I want to find products related to product no. 5

- get all visitor_id(s) who have seen product no. 5
- get all products and count them, seen by users above (except product no. 5)
- limit the query to let's say 10 results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want all products (which id is other than 5) AND viewed by the visitors who viewed no. 5? You can try something like this: (just off the top of my head, not tested)

```
SELECT product, COUNT(id) num
FROM the_table
WHERE
    visitor_id IN  ( SELECT DISTINCT visitor_id FROM the_table WHERE product='5' AND visitor_id!='this_visitor_id' ) AND
    product != '5'
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY num DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from your question, here is my answer.I have not tested the data though.

```
select visitor_id,product, count(visitor_id) 
from <your table>
where product=(select product from <your table> where id = (select max(id) from <your table>))
group by product

union

select visitor_id,product, count(visitor_id)
from <your table>
where product not in (select product from <your table> where id = (select max(id) from <your table>))
```